# Removing nested subscribeNext in reactive pipeline

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to construct a reactive pipeline where a change in some input signals will trigger off an asynchronous web api request. But I do not need to perform anything in the subscribeNext block of the web api.

This is how it looks:

```
RACSignal *inputChanged = [[RACSignal merge:@[ RACObserve(self, input1), RACObserve(self, input2) ]] throttle:0.5];

@weakify(self)
[[[inputChanged
  subscribeNext:^(id x) {
      @strongify(self)
      [[self asyncWebAPI]
       subscribeNext:^(id x) {
       }];
  }];
```

This works. But it isn't elegant because of the nested subscribeNext: and the second subscribeNext is just to make the asyncWebAPI a hot signal.

Is there a better way to construct this pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `-flattenMap:`. For example:

```
[[inputChanged
    flattenMap:^(id _) {
        @strongify(self);
        return [self asyncWebAPI];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        // Do stuff
    }];
```

Comment: I tried this before. But what if I didn't need to "do stuff"? Do I just use an empty block? Or is there an operator that will make the asyncWebAPI a hot signal when inputChanged?

Comment: Your question seemed to be asking how to remove the nested subscribe. It's always necessary to subscribe to make a cold signal become hot. The minimal way to do that would be `subscribeCompleted:^{}`.

Comment: Thanks Dave. The subscribeCompleted:^{} was indeed what I was looking for.